# Set padding for all content except images and few more elements

Tags: images, media, content

I want to have left and right 10px padding for all content inside post/page, but not for images, videos, galleries, tweets, pre, hr and few more. So that elements must be full width.

So I set:

```
.content {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Now I bring desired elements back to no-padding by setting negative margins:

```
pre,
hr,
.gallery {
  margin-right: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

And that works like expected, but not for images. So this:

```
.wp-caption {
  margin-right: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Doesn't work. It does work for right margin OR left if I set float:left, but not both right and left at a time. 
I tried to remove all theme's styles to figure out what to blame for such behavior, but it didn't help.

Also, Wordpress adds 10px to the width of .wp-caption container. Why is that? Does it have something to do with my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Link to the test site?

Comment: @MartinMetsalu Sorry, it's on localhost, can't share it right now..

Comment: Cannot provide you an answer without seeing any relevant code. Just the CSS code you provided is not enough.